# High Variance on CNN

Tags: cnn, overfitting, regularization

I'm using a shallow CNN for my current project [[this one]](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/57152/cnn-architecture-for-measuring-object-distances). I have a training dataset consisting of 1000 samples and a test dataset of 400 samples. I'm using the test dataset to choose the best hyperparameters for the NN (the ones which give the smallest loss). The problem is that, when I repeat the execution (with the same hyperparameters) a few times, I obtain a very different loss each run.

There are two different sources of randomness that affect each run:

- The split of the training dataset in the different minibatches used for training
- The weights initialization of the network

The architecture of the CNN is the following one: a conv layer consisting of only two filters, a max pool layer, a fully connected layer with 16 neurons and the output layer, with only one unit. The activation function is ReLu.

My hypothesis is that my model depends a lot on the weights initialization (I'm currently using **Xavier Initialization**). I have tried using **Dropout** to prevent this high variance, which has helped to some extent, and also tested different batch sizes for training. My next step will be introducing batch normalization.

What else should I do to solve this problem?